# VBA realtime filter Listbox through Textbox

Tags: vba, filter, textbox, listbox

I would like to filter a Listbox created from a list of values stored in a worksheet depending on text written in a textbox contained in the same userform.

My Listbox has 4 or 5 columns (depending on OptionField selection) and I would like to search all the columns for the text written.

Example: I write "aaa" in TextField and the Listbox should return a list based on all the lines whose column 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 contain "aaa".

Below my code to refresh the list on OptionField selection (this code does not produce any error, it is just to show how I create my list):

```
Sub RefreshList()

Dim selcell, firstcell As String
Dim k, i As Integer
Dim r as long
i = 0
k = 0

' reads parameters from hidden worksheet

If Me.new_schl = True Then

    firstcell = Cells(3, 4).Address
    selcell = firstcell

    Do Until IsEmpty(Range("" & selcell & "")) And i = 2
        If IsEmpty(Range("" & selcell & "")) Then i = i + 1
        k = k + 1
        selcell = Cells(1 + k, 7).Address(0, 0)
    Loop

        k = k - 1
        selcell = Cells(1 + k, 7).Address(0, 0)

    With Me.ListBox1

        .ColumnCount = 4
        .ColumnWidths = "50; 80; 160; 40"
        .RowSource = ""
        Set MyData = Range("" & firstcell & ":" & selcell & "")
        .List = MyData.Cells.Value

        For r = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .List(r, 3) = "" Or .List(r, 3) = "0" Then
                .RemoveItem r
            End If
        Next r

    End With

Else

    firstcell = Cells(3, 11).Address
    selcell = firstcell

    Do Until IsEmpty(Range("" & selcell & "")) And i = 11
        If IsEmpty(Range("" & selcell & "")) Then i = i + 1
        k = k + 1
        selcell = Cells(1 + k, 15).Address(0, 0)
    Loop

        k = k - 1
        selcell = Cells(1 + k, 15).Address(0, 0)

    With Me.ListBox1

        .ColumnCount = 5
        .ColumnWidths = "40; 40; 160; 40; 40"
        .RowSource = ""
        Set MyData = Range("" & firstcell & ":" & selcell & "")
        .List = MyData.Cells.Value

        For r = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .List(r, 3) = "" Or .List(r, 3) = "0" Then
                .RemoveItem r
            End If
        Next r

    End With

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: is there a problem with your code? Where does it throw an error?

Comment: Nope, my code is for you to take a look on how I populate my listbox.

I tried to    RemoveItem    but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could come out with something!

```
Sub Filter_Change()

Dim i As Long
Dim Str As String

Str = Me.Filter.Text

Me.RefreshList

If Not Str = "" Then
    With Me.ListBox1

        For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If InStr(1, LCase(.List(i, 0)), LCase(Str)) = 0 And InStr(1, LCase(.List(i, 1)), LCase(Str)) = 0 And _
              InStr(1, LCase(.List(i, 2)), LCase(Str)) = 0 And InStr(1, LCase(.List(i, 3)), LCase(Str)) = 0 Then

                .RemoveItem i

            End If
        Next i

    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know, the answer is couple of years old...

But I thought I'd share solution that works the best for me, because the filter is blazing fast even when there are thousands of items in the list. It is not without a "catch", though:
it uses a Dictionary object

```
Option Explicit
Dim myDictionary As Scripting.Dictionary

Private Sub fillListbox()
    Dim iii As Integer

    Set myDictionary = New Scripting.Dictionary

    ' this, here, is just a "draft" of a possible loop 
    ' for filling in the dictionary
    For iii = 1 To RANGE_END
        If Not myDictionary.Exists(UNIQUE_VALUE) Then
            myDictionary.Add INDEX, VALUE
        End If
    Next

    myListbox.List = myDictionary .Items

End Sub

Private Sub textboxSearch_Change()
    Dim Keys As Variant

    Keys = myDictionary .Items
    myListbox.List = Filter(Keys, textboxSearch.Text, True, vbTextCompare)

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call fillListbox
End Sub
```