# VBA Live-filter listbox via textbox & save multiple selections from listbox in one cell

Tags: arrays, vba, filter, listbox, userform

Hello again community,

After I got so much help from you with my last [Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269067/excel-vba-make-textbox-input-optional/38270130?noredirect=1#comment64043921_38270130), that promted me to rework the entire code in a more efficient manner, I would like to ask two more questions regarding the same Project.

(1) I would like to implement a live-filter in my listbox **CGList1**, which is connected to the textbox **SearchCGList1**. Whenever someone types in the textbox, the results in the listbox should be adjusted. I found this [Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060306/vba-realtime-filter-listbox-through-textbox) on your website, as well as this Article 3 on an external Webpage. However, due to my very limited skills, I have not been able to adapt it properly. More later.

(2) After multiple items from the same listbox **CGList1** have been transferred to the second listbox **CGList2** via a button (which works like a treat), I would like to save them in the same cell (Range "BM") on my Worksheet **Meta DB**. For this problem I also used Google extensively and tried to adapt the findings (see links below) for my code - without success.

I hope that the Patient ones amongst you can help me out once again, in the knowledge that I am trying to learn as much as possible. My Problem is that for a lot of things, I simply do not know what to look for.

My preliminary code for Problem 1:

CGList1 and CGList2 have no code. They are populated in the **Userform_Initialize sub** via:

```
'Fill Material Groups Listbox1 dynamically
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Commodity Groups")
    'Range to 500 in order to allow for further additions
    Set rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A500").End(xlUp))
End With

Me.CGList1.ColumnWidths = "20;80"


For Each cell In rng.Cells
'Filter out blanks
If cell <> "" Then
    With Me.CGList1
        .AddItem cell.value
        .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cell.Offset(0, 1).value
    End With
End If
Next cell
```

I cannot just use .AddItem and then filter through the columns like you find in many examples online because it needs to be dynamic and there are many blanks in between the selection items on the Worksheet.

The buttons:

```
Private Sub addCGbutton_Click()

For i = 0 To CGList1.ListCount - 1
    If CGList1.Selected(i) = True Then
        'Copy only CG Name, not respective number/letter combination (only more work to cut out when working with it later)
        CGList2.AddItem CGList1.List(i, 1)
    End If
Next i

End Sub

'Delete selected Commodity Groups from List 2 for re-selection
Private Sub delCGbutton_Click()

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

For i = 0 To CGList2.ListCount - 1
    If CGList2.Selected(i - counter) Then
        CGList2.RemoveItem (i - counter)
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

After a lot of trial and failure trying to adapt the linked approaches from other people, I tried something more simple:

```
Private Sub SearchCGList1_Change()

'Only show with textbox matching items in CGList1 (filter)

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT fieldname FROM table WHERE fieldname = "
strSQL = strSQL & "'" & Me!SearchCGList1 & "*'"
strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY fieldname;"

Me!SearchCGList1.RowSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

But without success.

Regarding Problem 2:

To save the multiple selections from CGList2 in Range BM on Worksheet "Meta DB", I toyed around a lot and my last try was:

```
Save multiple selections from Commodity Group List 2 to the same cell in Excel
Dim listItems As String, c As Long

With CGList2
    For c = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(c) Then listItems = listItems & .List(c) & ", "
    Next c
End With

Range("BM") = Left(listItems, Len(listItems) - 2)
```

Usually, all my other UserForm entries are saved with a single command button in the following fasion:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'Define all relevant WBs we will be working with
Dim wbInput As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Meta DB")
Dim LastRow As Long


'Save Userform Inputs
With ws
    .Activate
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    .
    .
    Range("BK" & LastRow).value = Me.payinfo90
    Range("BL" & LastRow).value = Me.payinfo90more
    'Risk Management - Residual Information
    Range("BM" & LastRow).value = Me.CGList2
    Range("BN" & LastRow).value = Me.suppsince
    .
    .
End With

End Sub
```

Again, I thank everyone who took the time to read my post and answer with tips on what to improve.

Everyone have a great day.

Comment: Is this in Access?  If so something like the SQL building solution would do it, using like so `select x from y where z like '*" & me.lstOne & "*'"`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, not that I am aware, unless I did it by accident haha. I am too new to VBA

Comment: What program are you using Access or Excel?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, Excel

Comment: And is the data on excel sheets?  If so you could use a helper column to do the searching, then link your listbox to this and not try to populate it.

Comment: Yes, the listbox CGList1 is filled from the Worksheet "Commodity Groups" and then, after using the add button, fills the CGList2, which is  the basis for the multiple selections supposed to be saved in problem 2 in the other Worksheet "Meta DB" range "BM" & LastRow. Both are in the same Workbook.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the helper column? And thank you already for your time!

Comment: @Gary_Evans, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Using a helper column with array formula.

So if say you had your data for the 1st list box in a1:a10 and the selection from this listbox is placed in D1, the 2nd complete listbox selections are in B1:B10, but not used, then in E1:E10, I have the following array formula filled down, so you would populate the 2nd listbox off the helper column E.

Beginning with 
`=INDEX($B$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF(LEFT($B$1:$B$10,LEN($D$1))=$D$1,ROW($B$1:$B$10),""),ROWS($E$1:$E1)),1)`

Containing
`=INDEX($B$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$1,$B$1:$B$10))),ROW($B$1:$B$10)),ROWS($E$1:E1)),1)`

You need to press CTRL SHIFT and ENTER for array formula.

Comment: I get your idea, but I am not sure that it would work. Here are two Pictures to illustrate the process:

http://imgur.com/a/olTqe

If I do it your way, I think I would Need to cut out parts of the string first, the numerical part in the beginning to be precise, right?-------It really has to be dynamic and it also has many spaces inbetween each selection.

Comment: Yes, just on that example, if you used FIND(D1,B1:b10) for example, it would do fuzzy searching.  LIke so `=INDEX($B$1:$B$10,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$1,$B$1:$B$10))),ROW($B$1:$B$10)),ROWS($E$1:E1)),1)`

Comment: I guess my Problem is that you assume I can save the selection from Listbox1 into D1, but that was my second Problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not manage with linear programming. Do you maybe have ideas for changes in my VBA code, that would accomplish the same?